# Various issues while viewing website on Iphone;Website not centered & Footer not spanning bottom

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

I need help solving some issues I am having while viewing this website on an Iphone. The website is working on IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari on my Mac and PC.

www.the90sareback.com
user: test
pass: Testing@123  (case sensative)

**Issue 1: Website is not centered in iPhone browser.** Visual of problem: http://imgur.com/7aXOvLK&qbAQ6zP#0

The Website is not being centered on the iphone browser. The left and right space is uneven and this makes no sense to me as I have the main content wrapper set to Margin: 0 Auto;. The left margin is a sliver and the right margin in much larger.

```
#content-wrapper {
width:1180px;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
background-image:url("style/images/papertile.png");
background-repeat:repeat-y;
```

**Issue 2: Footer is not going completely across the bottom of the screen. Seen in above image.** Visual of problem: see first link above.

I have tried messing with Min-width in the footer css and although it did extend the footer the text inside of the footer was not centered thus is not a solution in my eyes. I have also

```
.footer {
background-image:url("style/images/strip1.jpg");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
position:absolute;
height:124px;
margin:230px auto 0;
width:100%;
    left:0;  
    right:0;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Issue 1:** You have a link that is extending past the limits of it's container. This is normally because browsers don't like breaking links. See screenie: http://grab.by/rqNU

Honestly, I wouldn't show links like this, but instead have it be the href value of the header of that article/post. Or maybe a simple CTA like 'Las Vegas Weekly article'?

**Issue 2:** I would try adding left and right attributes to the footer css.

```
margin: 230px auto 0; //make sure to have the trailing '0' for no bottom margin.
width: 100%;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

Comment: Thank you, I took your advice and fixed the href issue. But the website not centering and the footer issue remain. Great advice otherwise, I would up vote you but I need more rep!